# How many different images are there in a dynamic wallpaper?

Tags: wallpaper

I just started using mac OS Catalina (just switched from Windows) and I love the dynamic wallpaper feature.

How many images make up the dynamic wallpaper? Does it change every 24 hours and is therefore composed of 24 different images?

Answer (score 2):

The number of images can vary depending on which dynamic wallpaper is chosen.  You can see how many images there are, for yourself.  In Finder, go to the “/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/“ folder, select whichever file you are interested in, and open it in Preview.  The dynamic wallpapers all have a file extension of ‘.heic’.

Comment: It's actually `/Library/Desktop Pictures/`

Comment: @Steve it used to be `/Library/Desktop Pictures` , since Catalina it is `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/`